# Why react doesn't update state in "then" promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, es6-promise

I have a table with `Delete` button in each row. When you delete the row, the Client will send request do the API asynchronously. Which means, that if you delete multiple rows quickly, you don't have to wait for one request to finish, to send another Delete request. When you click `Delete` button and request was send, the button will be disabled (before the response comes back and the row will disappear).

This is the function that handles delete in the Container:

```
  const [deletingTeams, setDeletingTeams] = useState([]);

  const handleDelete = (teamId) => {
    setDeletingTeams([...deletingTeams, teamId]);

    deleteTeam(teamId).then(() => {    
      console.log(deletingTeams); <---- This prints EMPTY array. Why????   
      let newState = deletingTeams.filter((id) => id !== teamId);
      setDeletingTeams(newState);
    });
  };
```

Very simple. `deletingTeams` is an array that holds ids of teams that are being deleted at the moment (the response didn't comeback from that API, that deletion was successful).

In line 3 (`setDeletingTeams([...deletingTeams, teamId]);`) I'm adding new teamId to the array, and it works. New array is being passed to the `List` component and `Delete` button is indeed disabled. **BUT**...

...when response comes back, in `then` promise, I want to remove that `teamId` from the array. The problem is, that `deletingTeams` array is already empty (before the filter). Why??

Thanks for the explanation,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State updates are async - you are not guaranteed to see latest value of the updated state straight away.

Use the callback approach to filter and set the state.

```js
const [deletingTeams, setDeletingTeams] = useState([]);

const handleDelete = (teamId) => {
  setDeletingTeams([...deletingTeams, teamId]);

  deleteTeam(teamId).then(() => {
    // console.log(deletingTeams); //<---- state updates are async - you will see the latest value of the state in the next re-render
    // let newState = deletingTeams.filter((id) => id !== teamId); //<---- remove this
    setDeletingTeams((prev) => prev.filter((id) => id !== teamId)); //<--- use call back approach to set the state
  });
};
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Just the follow up question: should I make it the same (use previous state) with `setDeletingTeams([...deletingTeams, teamId]);` ?

Comment: yes you can .. to be more safe ... just do `setDeletingTeams(prev => ([...prev, teamId]))` ..... in general, when you are dealing with updating state rapidly and when the state updates depends on prev state or component's prop, you need to use a callback function so that the state is perfectly updated...

Answer (score 2):

In short, the reason this is happening is because `deletingTeams` gets its value *before* your asynchronous call. The reasons why are subtle!

What's going on is, when you use `detetingTeams` in the `then` function for `deleteTeam`, the callback function you pass in is using a JavaScript feature called [function closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). The variable `deletingTeams` is used in your `then` function - but it's not defined by that function! So it can't have local function scope. Where exactly is it coming from, then?

The answer is nuanced. The variable is defined in your first line: `const [deletingTeams, setDeletingTeams] = useState([]);`. At this point, the variable is assigned a value based on your components' current state - the teams you currently have before deleting. Then, you reference it in your function. At this time, the variable `deletingTeams` becomes added to the `then` functions' scope. It is a reference to the same variable outside the function!

Ok, so the reason that `deletingTeams` is an empty array is because it's an empty array when you create the `then` function, right? Not quite. Any changes to `deletingTeams` are reflected when you execute the `then` function. But in your example, `deletingTeams` never changes its value. Your component's state changes when you call `setDeletingTeams`, but you only look up the state once - at the beginning of the block of code. There's no magic that will change `deletingTeams`' value; for that, you have to call `useState` again.

`deletingTeams` is given a fresh value each time your component rerenders. But unfortunately, the `then` function's closure scope is only determined once. (Each time you rerender, you actually generate a new `then` function, scoped to that render's version of the `deletingTeams` variable!) The component may have rerendered, but the `then` block is still called with the same stale value.

So, altogether, here's what's going on:

1. `deletingTeams` is assigned a value in your first line: `const [deletingTeams, setDeletingTeams] = useState([]);`
2. You update the state with `setDeletingTeams`, but `useState` is only called once, so `deletingTeams` is never updates to match new values.
3. `deletingTeams` gets a new value on each new render of your component, but by then, your `then` function is unfortunately already bound to a specific, past `deletingTeams` variable that never updates.
4. So when your `then` block executes, `deletingTeams` has a stale value.

---

So what is the correct approach, then? We can read the state in the `then` function to get the freshest value of `deletingTeams`. It's simply `this.state.deletingTeams`. Here's more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#reading-state

(Because you're using arrow functions, the `then` function automatically uses the same `this` as the component, so everything should work.)

So this should do the trick:

```js
  const [deletingTeams, setDeletingTeams] = useState([]);

  const handleDelete = (teamId) => {
    setDeletingTeams([...deletingTeams, teamId]);

    deleteTeam(teamId).then(() => {    
      let newState = this.state.deletingTeams.filter((id) => id !== teamId);
      setDeletingTeams(newState);
    });
  };
```

(Be sure to use `this.state.deletingTeams` instead of calling `useState` again in this kind of situation. Calling `useState` inside of nested functions or callbacks can lead to bugs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)